# Redirection error on question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430075/loading-extjs-grid-from-an-xml-string-instead-of-file%e2%80%8e) won't open because of a redirection error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the same bug reported on MSE: [Redirect loop after editing a question title ending with no-break space, question mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233850/redirect-loop-after-editing-a-question-title-ending-with-no-break-space-questio)

Marc probably re-enabled the utf-8 url support and didn't close all the corners.

To sum this up, the title had a unicode special character in it. Such characters were ignored until very recently, now they affect the stub.

I have edited out the offensive character to stop the redirection. To fix such titles, you have to manually construct such URL and browse it: `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/{post id}/edit` e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6430075/edit

Comment: You beat me to this fix... too fast you are!

Comment: @bluefeet pure luck, I actually don't roam MSO that often. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Sheesh, unicode is fun; I have added checks to explicitly drop control/format characters when generating slugs. Thanks for finding my failure ;p

This has become an issue because we have recently enabled UTF-8 [character sets for urls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214531/convert-diacritics-to-normal-letters-in-the-profile-link/233832#233832) on all sites in the network (it was previously only enabled for "language" sites).